# Fix deprecated JRequest in Joomla 4

Tags: joomla-4.x

The following code use to work for generating variables for open graph data, but when I updated to Joomla 4 I now get an error because JRequest is deprecated.

```
$option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
$view = JRequest::getCmd('view');
if ($option=="com_content" && $view=="article") {
    $ids = explode(':',JRequest::getString('id'));
    $article_id = $ids[0];
    $article =& JTable::getInstance("content");
    $article->load($article_id);
    $theArticle = $article->get("title");
    $theImages = $article->get("images");   
    $pictures = json_decode($theImages); // Split the parameters apart
    $timage= "http://mywebsite.../".$pictures->{'image_intro'};
}
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addCustomTag( '
<meta name="twitter:title" content="'.mb_strimwidth(strip_tags($theArticle),0,225, " ...").'"=""/>
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="yoursite">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="yourcreator">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="'.JURI::current().'">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="'.mb_strimwidth(strip_tags($doc->getMetaData( 'description' )),0,225, " ...").'"=""/>
<meta name="twitter:image" content="'.$timage.'">

<meta property="og:title" content="'.$this->escape($this->item->title).'"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:email" content="";/>
<meta property="og:url" content="'.str_replace('" ','&quot;',juri::current()).'"="">
<meta property="og:image" content="'.$timage.'"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
<meta property="og:description" content="'.strip_tags($this->item->introtext).'"/>
');
```

How can I rewrite this to work with Joomla 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance you would replace JRequest with application input.

```
$JInput = Factory::getApplication()->input;
$view = $JInput->get('view','','string');
echo $view;
```

Sorry for my short answer but I'm traveling. this should point you in the right direction. Welcome to the JSE.

Answer (score 1):

JRequest had been deprecated since Joomla 3, so the [documentation available for Joomla 3](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) is still valid for Joomla 4.

If you want to convert the old classes to the namespaces you can use this [script](https://github.com/techjoomla/joomla-3x-to-4x-migration-tools/blob/main/joomla-39x-to-4x-namespaces-script/namespaces.php) or use the list as cheatsheet.

For a comprehensive list of deprecated classes, removed classes and other stuff that has changed between J3.10 and J4 you should read the list of [potential backward compatibility issues](https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_4).